# OBOE: Need help understanding, possible type conversion issue

Tags: c++

I have an algorithm that its main purpose is decoding, converting, or what have you a string of uppercase letters (A-Z) into a number. This is almost like converting a base 26 number into base 10, however I believe that a base 26 number encoded would actually include numbers, I am working strictly with uppercase letters, I digress.

I have an implantation working in C++11, in fact most of the controller algorithm was a direct copy, with a slight change to the indexOf method.

The C++11 version works as I expect it to. So initially I thought the new indexOf method was incorrect, but after a simple test, it is working as expected. I have narrowed down the problem to a line in the convertTo10 where I am calling the pow function.

As you can see from the Serial.println()'s in the convertTo10 method, the output is printing exactly what we expect, 0 & 26.

However, the output of this function is 25. WHAT?

I have read the docs on the pow method from the Arduino lib, and it takes in two floats and returns a double. Even if the issue was a type conversion issue, converting a double to an int truncates the number, it does not round it. Well, this is from working with C++.

Any help with this issue would be much appreciated.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#include <Wire.h>


const char _values[26] = {
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J',
    'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T',
    'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'
};

const int _val_len = 26;


int indexOf(char needle);
int convertTo10(String value, int len);

String x = "BA";
int len = 2;

void loop() {  
  Serial.print(x);
  Serial.print("=> ");
  Serial.println(convertTo10(x, 2));
  delay(50000);
}

int convertTo10(String value, int len) {
    int lastIndex = len - 1;
    double output = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    Serial.println();
    for (int i = lastIndex; i >= 0; i--) {
        int r = indexOf(value[i]);

        output += (r * pow((_val_len, pos));
        Serial.print("     output => ");
        Serial.println( output );
        pos++;
    }
    return output;
}

int indexOf(char needle) {

    int first = 0; 
    int last = _val_len - 1; 
    int mid;  

  do {   
    mid = (first + last) / 2; 

    if (_values[mid] == needle)
      return mid;
    if (_values[mid] > needle)
      last = mid - 1;
    else
      first = mid + 1; 
  } while (first <= last);

  return -1; 
}
```

For Reference, Here what it is outputting:

```
BA =>
     output => 0.00
     output => 26.00 
25
```

Comment: Also posted on the [Arduino Forum](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=515933.0).

Comment: You can make the return value be 26 in this case by rounding. That is change the last line of your conversion function to be: `return round (output);`. The fact that it is returning 25 indicates that the `pow` function is not giving an exact result. If you increase the number of decimal places printed you will see that you are actually getting `25.9999961853`.

Answer (score 3):

way too complicated:

```
int convertTo10(char *num_26, int len) {
  int tmp = 0;  //hold the output
  int i = 0;  //indexing the input
  while (len--) tmp = tmp * 26 + (num_26[i++]-'A');
  return tmp;
}
```

note:

1. "* 26" can be further simplified;
2. error checking could be built-in here, or somewhere else (better).
3. better structuring could get rid of one of the temporary variables.

Comment: Thank you for the optimized code! However, I was hoping I could get an explanation on what is happening in the code I posted? What did I do wrong?

Comment: What you did wrong was to rely on a floating point number to be exact.  They hardly ever are.

Comment: @Delta_G I realize this now. Thank you for the correction, I should have just waiting until the morning to revisit the problem, instead of ask dumb questions. I do appreciate the help.

Comment: @dannyf As much as I appreciate this solution and the time and effort you took to help me. I have to mark this solution as incorrect. I have verified that  on a atmel2560 compiled with avr-gcc, and on Debian x64 compiled with g++ under standard 11, this method will always return 0.

Comment: This code fails because `i` is not initialized. Otherwise it is conceptually similar to my answer. If you change the third line to `int i = 0;` it works.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is incredibly complex for a simple thing like converting a number from another base. This works (prints 26):

```
const char * test = "BA";

long convertTo10 (const char * s)
  {
  long result = 0;
  for (const char * p = s; *p; p++)
    {
    result *= 26;   // base
    result += *p - 'A';  // make zero-relative
    }
  return result;
  } // end of convertTo10

void setup() 
  {
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println ("Starting.");
  Serial.println (convertTo10 (test));
  }


void loop() { }
```

With input "CBA" it prints 1378 as expected.  Sketch size: 2,300 bytes of program memory. The sketch size reduces to 2,236 bytes if I make the function return `int` (as you did) rather than `long`.

You don't need to use `String` (in fact it saves RAM and avoids memory fragmentation to not use it). You don't need to pass the length, with both `char*` and `String` you can deduce the length. If you use `long` as the return type you can handle larger numbers.

By using `pow` you are bringing in a library which is not needed and which will consume program memory. By using `double` you are introducing possible inaccuracies since double does not necessarily store numbers exactly. Your code used 7,604 bytes of program memory once I corrected the syntax error and added an empty `setup` function.

---

Also, the method I illustrate above is *much* faster. I timed it at converting "BA" in 4.3 µs, whereas the method using the `pow` function takes 442 µs. So the simpler method is also 100 times faster.